# AdWords Html5 external data (json)

Tags: google-ads-api

I am seeking confirmation the follow can or can't be done.

I need to show external json data in html5 adwords banner - modify that data on hourly basis - direct calls to external domains in banners not allowed.

Not static json uploaded with ad, need updatable datasource (long campaign, prices changing)

Only found this:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/external-data

Can anyone provide sample if I can access the "businessdata" from banner? - there is a way to update such data by schedule in adwords script - but found no example how I could access that data from banner on its display